Consulta SQL sin nombre de campo
Tengo una macro en VBA Outlook que se conecta a una lista SharePoint mediante ADO.
En esta lista, el nombre de la primera columna editable, por defecto, es "Título"; pero en algunas máquinas de compañeros es "Title".
Esto supone un problema porque al hacer una consulta SQL a la lista, si filtro por el campo "Título", en algunos usuarios no funciona porque no encuentra el campo, y hay que modificar la consulta por "Title".
Mi pregunta es si se podía hacer la consulta filtrando por el fields(1) (1=indice del campo TÍtulo en la tabla)
En vez de
SELECT * FROM [LISTA] WHERE [LISTA].Título='HOLA'

Algo del estilo
SELECT * FROM [LISTA] WHERE [LISTA].FIELDS(1)='HOLA'

Muchas gracias!!!!

Hola. Poder se podría, creando un procedimiento almacenado al cual le pases el índice de la columna que quieres consultar. Evidentemente, estaríamos hablando de una consulta más costosa que si lo hicieras del modo habitual, porque tendrías que consultar a INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS y hacer validaciones, como por ejemplo, verificar que existe una columna en ese índice.

ADO es un conector... sin saber a que base de datos vas, es dificil poder contestar... igual, lo mas probable es que quieras hacer eso porque estes buscando alguna forma de hacer una consulta parametrizada de alguna forma, y esa no seria la forma ideal...

Disculpad que he sido muy escueto en el planteamiento pq pensaba que era una cuestión relativamente trivial.....
Tengo una conexión a una lista SharePoint, en el que la columna por defecto es "Título" pero en algunas máquinas de compañeros es "Title", por eso, al hacer una consulta filtrando por el campo "Título", en algunos usuario peta pq no encuentra el campo, y hay que modificar la consulta por "Title", de ahí que quisiera saber si se podía hacer la consulta filtrando por el fields(1) (1=indice del campo en la tabla)
Gracias!

Bueno.. eso que pusiste en comentarios es ultra importante y cambia totalmente el sentido de la pregunta... para empezar, queres pegarle a sharepoint, lo cual cambia radicalmente el concepto de la pregunta. por favor, edita la pregunta y pone toda la informacion como corresponde. Es mas, agrega el tag sharepoint y saca el vba que no tiene nada que ver con tu problema...

OK, done! disculpad

Puedes determinar dinámicamente el nombre de la columna y construir la sentencia SQL con esta información, por ejemplo:
Public Function nombre_primera_columna(table_name As String) as String
  Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
  rst.Open "select * from  " + table_name + " where 1=0", _
        CurrentProject.Connection 

  nombre_primera_columna = rst.Fields(0).Name
End Function

...

Dim MiQuery As String
MiQuery = "select * from [LISTA] where [LISTA].[" & nombre_primera_columna("[LISTA]") & "] = 'HOLA'"

Debes estar consciente que esto implica la realización de un select sobre la misma lista, que tiene una condición que no se va a cumplir nunca, para que no haga viajar datos por la red, pero que implica tiempo y recursos para su realización.
A menos que guardaras una configuración (que puede fallar), no se me ocurre otra manera de que la consulta se adapte a el nombre cambiante de la columna.
Finalmente, como puedes ver, el índice del primer campo de la tabla, para VBA, es 0, no 1.
